# regex expression working in chrome but throwing error in safari

Tags: angular, regex

The below expression working in chrome but throwing error in safari
regex expression:

```
/(?<=>#tableVits)\w+(.*?#tableVite<)/g;
```

Comment: Please also include the text against which you are trying to match this regex.

Comment: [Safari doesn't support lookbehinds](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind)

Comment: <tablevits>testing</tablevites><tablevits>testing</tablevites>

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
new RegExp(`(?<=>#tableVits)\\w+(.*?#tableVite<)`, `g`)
```

Maybe it will work